# For all the records on a object how to enforce that there can only be one record where a checkbox field would be checked?

Tags: trigger, validation, adderror

I've a checkbox field on an object. Now, for all the records on this object there can only be one record where this checkbox field would be checked. Need help here as to how do I implement this?

Edit:Have written this code, but this is not working.

```
trigger updateGenerateOutputCheckbox on ObjectX__c (before insert,before update) {
for(ObjectX__c x:Trigger.new){
    Integer count = [SELECT COUNT() FROM ObjectX__c WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName=:x.RecordType.DeveloperName AND CheckboxField__c=TRUE];
        if(count>1){
            Trigger.newMap.get(x.Id).addERROR('There cannot be more than one x record of this type with checkbox checked');
        }

}
```

}

Comment: You can write a trigger on that object and achieve this functionality.

Comment: There are six record types on the object. Now per record type there should be only one record with the checkbox checked. Need help as to how the code for this would look like